# Javascript WebSocket connection to wss server failed

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I have a wss server running at

> wss://myurl.azurecontainer.io:8000/

This websocket works fine if I connect to it via programs like Postman. When connected to the socket, it set up a livestream where every second it returns the location of a vehicle. The problem is that when using javascript on a website I develop, I get the error message

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://myurl.azurecontainer.io:8000/' failed:

And the code where it  fails is `ws = new WebSocket(url);`.  I have checked the if the url is correct, and it is correct.
I have tried multiple browsers (Firefox, Brave, Edge, Chrome) and all cannot cannot connect to the socket.

How can I fix it?

I have tried multiple browsers (Firefox, Brave, Edge, Chrome) and all cannot cannot connect to the socket.

The websocket is set up via a python script that is using a Kafka stream with `ssl_context.load_cert_chain(cert.pem, key.pem)`

Full error

```
Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, …}
isTrusted
: 
true
bubbles
: 
false
cancelBubble
: 
false
cancelable
: 
false
composed
: 
false
currentTarget
: 
WebSocket {url: wss://myurl.azurecontainer.io:8000/, readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}
defaultPrevented
: 
false
eventPhase
: 
0
returnValue
: 
true
srcElement
: 
WebSocket {url: wss://myurl.azurecontainer.io:8000/, readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}
target
: 
WebSocket {url: wss://myurl.azurecontainer.io:8000/, readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}
timeStamp
: 
4396
type
: 
"error"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Event
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: are ws/wss connections subject to CORS? Is there any chance you can get a more descriptive error than just "failed"? I don't know, by looking in the browser developer tools for example

Comment: There are no CORS errors found in developer tools

Comment: fine, I didn't say it IS a CORS error, but "failed" is hardly useful - perhaps your code is obfuscating a useful error code

Comment: is your websocket server behind a reverse proxy?

Comment: Not behind a reverse proxy

Comment: Like @JaromandaX said: The developer tools should be outputting a more complete error message to the console. What does it say there?

Comment: What is inside the main post is what I get after the error. 
ws.onerror = function(error) {
  console.error('WebSocket Error: ', error);
};
What would add to this?

Comment: nowhere in the "Full error" you added is the string `WebSocket Error` ... therefore, `console.error('WebSocket Error: ', error);` isn't ever run